# Question about when to use lua colon syntax

Tags: oop, syntax, lua, coronasdk

```
local Public = {}

function Public.new(ent)
  local State = {}


  function State:update(player)
    ent:setLinearVelocity(0,0)
  end

  function State:start(player)
    ent.fixedRotation = true
    self.attackTimer = _G.m.addTimer(200, function()
      ent:setState('attacking', player)
    end)
  end

  function State:exit(player)
    ent.fixedRotation = false
    timer.cancel(self.attackTimer)
  end

  return State
end

return Public
```

I'm using a linter and its complaining that I'm using the colon unnecessarily for my `update` and `exit` methods.  The reason I do this is to keep all my methods uniform.  Sometimes I need `self` and sometimes I don't.

But in general is there any advantage to using colon on these at all?  It seems like if i have something like `State:start` then I could just reference `State` directly. I could do `State.attackTimer` vs `self.attackTimer`..

Why would you ever really need the colon?  If you have access to the table that holds the method then you have access to self.. right?

Comment: Some categories of lint warnings are just suggestions, not always things that "should" be fixed. If you understand why the linter says this, thought about it, and decided you still want to keep the interface you have, in my opinion you can just check that off.

Comment: I understand.. but trying to understand why the colon notation even exists.

you could just do local self = State on the top of the function and be good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:` syntax is a great tool when you are making a class using a table and a metatable.

Your code above, rather then creating a class, creates an encapsulated set of functions. which have access to `State` as an upvalue.

I will use this class from [Lua Users - SimpleLuaClasses](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SimpleLuaClasses) as an example:

```
Account = {}
Account.__index = Account

function Account:create(balance)
   local acnt = {}             -- our new object
   setmetatable(acnt,Account)  -- make Account handle lookup
   acnt.balance = balance      -- initialize our object
   return acnt
end

function Account:withdraw(amount)
   self.balance = self.balance - amount
end

-- create and use an Account
acc = Account:create(1000)
acc:withdraw(100)
```

Here we have an instance(`acc`) of the `Account` class. To adjust or modify the values in this specific instance of `Account` we can not refer to `Account.balance` inside of `Account:withdraw`. We need a reference to the table where the data is stored, and that is where passing that table using `:` comes in.

`acc:withdraw(100)` is just syntactic sugar for `acc.withdraw(acc, 100)` passing in our table as the first param `self`. When you define `Account:withdraw(amount)` there is an implicate first variable `self` the definition could be written as `Account.withdraw(self, amount)`